# I cannot import matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to improt matplotlib for my Jupyter and Im facing this issue:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:188
    184 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    186 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    187 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 188 from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
    189 from matplotlib.cbook import sanitize_sequence
    190 from matplotlib._api import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py:27
     25 from matplotlib import _api, cbook
     26 from matplotlib.cbook import ls_mapper
---> 27 from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
     28 from matplotlib._fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
     29 from matplotlib._enums import JoinStyle, CapStyle

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:57
     55 import matplotlib as mpl
     56 import numpy as np
---> 57 from matplotlib import _api, _cm, cbook, scale
     58 from ._color_data import BASE_COLORS, TABLEAU_COLORS, CSS4_COLORS, XKCD_COLORS
     61 class _ColorMapping(dict):

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py:22
     20 import matplotlib as mpl
     21 from matplotlib import _api, _docstring
---> 22 from matplotlib.ticker import (
     23     NullFormatter, ScalarFormatter, LogFormatterSciNotation, LogitFormatter,
     24     NullLocator, LogLocator, AutoLocator, AutoMinorLocator,
     25     SymmetricalLogLocator, AsinhLocator, LogitLocator)
     26 from matplotlib.transforms import Transform, IdentityTransform
     29 class ScaleBase:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py:143
    141 import matplotlib as mpl
    142 from matplotlib import _api, cbook
--> 143 from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
    145 _log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    147 __all__ = ('TickHelper', 'Formatter', 'FixedFormatter',
    148            'NullFormatter', 'FuncFormatter', 'FormatStrFormatter',
    149            'StrMethodFormatter', 'ScalarFormatter', 'LogFormatter',
   (...)
    155            'MultipleLocator', 'MaxNLocator', 'AutoMinorLocator',
    156            'SymmetricalLogLocator', 'AsinhLocator', 'LogitLocator')

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py:49
     46 from numpy.linalg import inv
     48 from matplotlib import _api
---> 49 from matplotlib._path import (
     50     affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox, update_path_extents)
     51 from .path import Path
     53 DEBUG = False

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path
```

I tried to uninstall and install, install a oldest version but didn't work also. I found a post saying to install 'msvc-runtime' and PIL by pip, but didn't work too :\

The funny thing is in my virtual envs , the import for matplotlib works, just in the "base" python don't work.

Comment: `DLL` means `C/C++ library` and often it is not part of Python and you have to download and install it manually.